# Mongodb query on json object

Tags: mongodb-query

I am trying to find a course based on my course json object. If I just have the course number 12712 and the lecture: A, then how can I find that course in a json object (the first object in the courses object) filled with many of these courses? My attempt at this is

```
db.courses.find({"courses.12712"})
```

but I am getting an error

> SNIPPET OF JSON OBJECT:
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("566f824641b9b2eba94a9ff4"), "courses" : { "12712"
>   : { "department" : "Civil & Environmental Engineering", "lectures" : [
>   { "instructors" : [ "Vanbriesen" ], "sections" : [ ], "lecture" : "A",
>   "meetings" : [ { "room" : "DH 2302", "location" : "Pittsburgh,
>   Pennsylvania", "end" : "04:20PM", "days" : "MW", "begin" : "03:00PM" }
>   ] } ], "name" : "Introduction to Sustainable Engineering", "units" :
>   12, "prereqs" : "", "semester" : [ "F" ], "coreqs" : "", "desc" :
>   "This course begins with an overview...." }}

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has `query operators` you can use the $`eq` operator to match the field you want (in your case its a number). Check out their official documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query-comparison/).

**Syntax:**

```
{ <field>: { $eq: <value> } }
```

In your case, you can probably try:

```
db.courses.find({ <property you want to match>: { $eq: "12712" } });
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator to determine a particular fields in document.

```
db.courses.find({"courses.12712" : { $exists:true }})
```

if you want to check that if lecture should be there with at least one element then

```
db.courses.find({"courses.12712" : { $exists:true },"courses.12712.lectures.0" : { $exists:true } })
```